# Connecting a flask application to a postgresql service running in a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application that uses PostgreSQL as its backend DB. I have installed Postgresql as a dockerized service (using docker-compose).

I am now running the postgresql successfully on my machine. I have entered all the relevant details to connect to the database (user, pwd, dbname, server address, server port) but I can't connect.

When I try to connect to the database, an exception is thrown in Flask (from the psycopg2):

```
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I check if postgresql is running, I get the following message:

```
$ service postgresql status
● postgresql.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

After reading a little bit more about Docker and PostgreSQL, I have come to understand why I can't connect - since postgresql is running in its own container - so the server address and port details I'm using in my db connection parameters are wrong.

Here is output from `docker-ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b7c8cbac0a3b        mbsolutions/tryton-server-gnuhealth:3.8   "/docker-entrypoint.s"   13 days ago         Up 12 days          0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   gnuhealth_tryton_1
0a4d9fd42544        mbsolutions/postgres-gnuhealth:3.0        "/docker-entrypoint.s"   13 days ago         Up 12 days          5432/tcp                 gnuhealth_db_1
```

My question is this:

What parameters (specifically db server address and port) should I use in my database connection parameters, so that I can connect to the dockerized postgresql service from my flask application?

Note: I have seen this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165348/using-a-postgresql-database-with-docker-and-flask-how-does-it-work), which seems similar, but solution given does not directly answer my question.

Comment: What is the connection string you are using?

Answer (score 0):

**======================== Correct Answer Start ========================**

You must map the postgres container port (5432) to be able to access it on your host.

Add this in the docker-compose.yml

```
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
```

**======================== Correct Answer End ========================**

Old answer kept for posterity :

You maybe want to use the `host` network.

Add this in the docker-compose.yml

```
network_mode: "host"
```

The container will not be isolated from your host itself.

Comment: Thanks, but that defeats the "containerisation" aspect of Docker. I would rather keep the containers separate.

Comment: Right, you should then map the postgres port to your host, I've modified the answer.

Comment: @Homunculus Reticulli Any update about using port mapping ?

Comment: Sorry, I stepped away from my desk. Thanks for the updated answer. What do you propose I use for the server address though? The container (I believe) is it's own machine with IP address (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: WIth port mapping, you can use your localhost address (127.0.0.1)

Comment: I have tried the various combinations you suggested, I get the same error posted in my question.